# Nightwatch 'For' Loop not executing commands

Tags: javascript, for-loop, nightwatch.js

I'm trying to create a loop within nightwatch.js that will;

- load a page
- assert an element
- click on this element

for a selection of pages.

Below is my code;

```
var carTypeHref = ['/type-hatchback/','/type-saloon/','/type-estate/','/type-4x4/']
var listCarTypeHref = carTypeHref[Symbol.iterator]();

module.exports = { 
  'navigate to small car type cfs landing page': function (browser) {
    browser
      .url(browser.launch_url + browser.globals.carsForSale + '/type-small-city/')
      .agreeCookiePolicy();
  },
  'navigate to car type cfs landing pages and check dealer link details': function (browser) {
    for (let carType of browser.globals.listCarTypeHref) {
      browser
      .url(browser.launch_url + browser.globals.carsForSale + (carType))
      .assert.elementPresent('.for-sale-result-item__dealer')
      .click('.for-sale-result-item__dealer')
    }
  },     
  'closing the browser': function (browser) {
    browser
      .browserEnd();
  },     
};
```

The urls load correctly, one by one as defined in **carTypeHref** and **listCarTypeHref**.

However, the rest of the commands within this loop don't appear to be executed;

```
.assert.elementPresent('.for-sale-result-item__dealer')
```

or

```
.click('.for-sale-result-item__dealer')
```

are not executed.

I'm a bit stuck as to why, so any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Do u try wait for the element visiblity before assert?  .waitForElementVisible('.for-sale-result-item__dealer', 1000)

Comment: Quick update on this.  So if I change the assertion to something that I know is incorrect, for example; `.assert.elementPresent('.for-saaaaale-result-item__dealer')` this test still passes?  The number of assertions is correct (in this example, the number of assertions is 1 compare to 27 with a correct assertion) but the overall test passes.  I'm presuming this is a nightwatch.js issue?